# What does “intergeneric writing” mean?

Tags: meaning

What is **intergeneric** writing?

I did a Google search to no avail. I am interested in learning about this genre, or something else that I could search for to draw more knowledge.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean [Cross-genre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-genre) or [multigenre](http://www.users.miamioh.edu/romanots/) writing?

Answer (score 2):

"Intergeneric writing" is a malappropriation of the phrase "inter-genre writing."  The latter involves writing in a manner that mixes aspects of multiple genres.

Comment: This seems plausible, but do you have any evidence that this is a malapropism rather than an established usage in some subculture?

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, but I cannot find any authoritative references at all online to "intergeneric writing," and if you look at the word "generic" it describes something that is lacking in distinguishing attributes, so how can you be "inter" (between) two or more things that have no distinguishing attributes?  The process of combining through either union or interpolation would yield the same result as each of the original components.

Answer (score 1):

The first [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22intergeneric+writing%22) result (other than this question, now) for the string `“intergeneric writing”` is a Facebook blog post which states the following:

> What is intergeneric writing?
>
> Intergeneric writing is when you combine genres in your narrative. You can incorporate seemingly unrelated genres together to tell the story. The type of genres you choose will enhance the story in some way.
> <sub>Source: [Qwiller, Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/qwillercreativewriting/posts/311220649004074)</sub>

The full post is available [here on their blog](http://qwillerwritingroom.blogspot.com/2013/03/intergeneric-writing.html), along with examples and specific prompts.

It may be worth noting that a [more recent post](http://qwillerwritingroom.blogspot.com/2014/08/more-intergenric-writing.html) spells it **“intergenric”**, making the meaning easier to see as a combination of “inter-” (between), “genre” (type), and “-ic” ([-ish](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ish)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall ever seeing the word before, but OED confirms my initial assumption that the usage relates to (taxonomic) ***genera***, not (literary) [***genres***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/genre)...

> ***intergeneric*** *- Formed or obtained from (individuals of) different **genera** (plural of [**genus**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/genus)).*

As @JeffSahol comments, a writing style incorporating aspects of multiple literary genres may be called ***cross-genre*** or ***multigenre***.